# managing manually scaled clusters

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm working on an AWS-hosted web service that lets a user spin up a box, perform a job on it, and then spin the box back down. because this relies on exclusive usage of a GPU, it's not a standard containers + ELB problem -- the task needs to be the only thing running on that box, and when it finishes, I want to terminate the instance.

I poked around at Terraform but it seems like the nature of its statefulness makes it difficult to spin up and down boxes like this (I'd have to keep changing the .tf file to add or remove machines). am I correct about that?

ideally, I'd like an "ip_address_of_new_box = api.provisionNewBoxInVPCAndRunContainer()" call. I could then put that IP address into my DB and a service would poll it until it finishes its task, at which time it calls "api.shutDownBox(ip_address_of_new_box)"

do I have to fall back on managing this manually with Boto or is there something smart that I can do here?

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here certainly isn't the "standard" Terraform use-case. It seems like this breaks down into three sub-problems:

1. Create an EC2 instance with a particular configuration and launch some software on it.
2. Monitor for the completion of a task on that new machine.
3. Terminate the EC2 instance.

Terraform can help you solve sub-problems 1 and 3 via some slightly-unusual usage:

- Write a Terraform configuration that describes the EC2 instance and any provisioning needed to start your software on it.
- Run `terraform apply` to create the instance, and stash the state file somewhere that you can find it once the job completes.
- Wait for the job to complete using some mechanism outside of Terraform.
- Retrieve the state stashed earlier and run `terraform destroy` to shut the instance down.

This assumes there's some orchestration script wrapping this process, using Terraform as the implementation of steps 1 and 3.

What Terraform brings to the table here is automatically maintaining the state (just the instance id in this case, really) so that the instance can be cleanly shut down, though if you are certain that an EC2 instance is all you will ever need Terraform is likely to be overkill here vs. just using the EC2 API directly and retaining the instance id and IP address yourself in some application-specific store.

---

Another option would be to use an external orchestration service like [AWS Data Pipeline](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/what-is-datapipeline.html), which can coordinate the process of [starting up an instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-how-task-runner-dp-managed.html), running a compute task on it, saving the result somewhere, and then shutting down the instance.

In this case there would be a one-time task to set up the Data Pipeline itself and the associated Task Runner that would start up your EC2 instance, and then ongoing usage would involve triggering the pipeline using the Data Pipeline API.

In principle Terraform could be used to coordinate the one-time setup of the data pipeline, and ongoing changes to its configuration. However, at the time of writing Terraform doesn't yet have support for Data Pipeline and so an alternative approach would be required.